# Claymore Eth Dual Miner: Acceptable rate of incorrect Ethereum shares

Tags: mining, claymore, shares

When I use Claymore in dual mining mode (no matter what combination - Ethereum + Decred, Ethereum + Pascal, Ethereum + Lbry), I'm unable to achieve zero incorrect shares for Ethereum (`Incorrect ETH shares: none`).

Even on cards with factory settings (not overclocked) and low `-dcri 10` - there are still incorrect shares about 0.5%.

Statistics (**S** key pressed in Claymore's window) after about 800 shares on 3 GPUs look like this:

[image]

Is that normal? And does it matter? (I mean, can it cause any sanctions from pool?) What are your stats?

Answer (score 0):

That is not normal, some days ago my stats on ethermine.org was great stats but the ETH was uploading slow and I saw the same problem like you.

I fixed it downloading the 2200 memory to 2100 and the issue was fix and I did not lose MH / s in the change.

I use 8 RX 580 and i don't know how much you need reduce.

**local.conf**

`globalcore 1200
globalmem 2100
globalpowertune 3
globalminer claymore`

**claymore.stub.conf**

`-dcri 20`